# define double constant as hexadecimal?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754, notation

I would like to have the closest number below 1.0 as a floating point. By reading wikipedia's article on [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double-precision_64_bit) I have managed to find out that the binary representation for 1.0 is `3FF0000000000000`, so the closest double value is actually `0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

The only way I know of to initialize a double with this binary data is this:

```
double a;
*((unsigned*)(&a) + 1) = 0x3FEFFFFF;
*((unsigned*)(&a) + 0) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Which is rather cumbersome to use.

Is there any better way to define this double number, if possible as a constant?

Comment: the only way is this... unless your C++ implementation has 64 bit integer support.

Comment: This is just nitpicking, but it is IEEE-754-1985 (not IEEE-745).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hexadecimal float and double literals do exist.
The syntax is 0x1.(mantissa)p(exponent in decimal)
In your case the syntax would be

```
double x = 0x1.fffffffffffffp-1
```

Comment: I've never heard of this syntax before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I think its part of the C99 standard. It works with GNU compilers, I don't about others.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I wrote an article about this recently: http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Added in C99.  Also supported in `printf`/`scanf` via the `%a` format specifier.  By far the best way to specify floating-point values in C.

Answer (score 3):

It's not safe, but something like:

```
double a;
*(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t *>(&a)) = 0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
```

However, this relies on a particular endianness of floating-point numbers on your system, so don't do this!

Instead, just put `DBL_EPSILON` in `<cfloat>` (or as pointed out in another answer, `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`) to good use.

Comment: Treating it as an integer should make it endian-independent (unless you have one of those weird "mixed endian" systems)

Comment: @Rick Regan: Who's to say that the "endianness" of your platform's representation of floating-point types is consistent with the representation of integer types?

Comment: Theoretically you're right -- but do you have an example (besides the mixed-endian “soft floats”)?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double const    x   = 1.0 - numeric_limits< double >::epsilon();

    cout
        << setprecision( numeric_limits< double >::digits10 + 1 ) << fixed << x
        << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make a `bit_cast` and use [fixed-width integer types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/cstdint.hpp), it can be done safely:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
R bit_cast(const T& pValue)
{
    // static assert R and T are POD types

    // reinterpret_cast is implementation defined,
    // but likely does what you expect
    return reinterpret_cast<const R&>(pValue);
}

const uint64_t target = 0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFFL;
double result = bit_cast<double>(target);
```

Though you can probably just [subtract `epsilon` from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947159/define-double-constant-as-hexadecimal/3947197#3947197).

Comment: Not sure why you went to the trouble of defining bit_cast when you could have just used `reinterpret_cast<double&>` directly. Still seems like a good solution.

Comment: @Mark: That wouldn't static assert both types are POD types, and would make it easier to break aliasing rules. (Admittedly I gave a more general solution than required; in this case just doing it directly works fine.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little archaic, but you can use a `union`.
Assuming a `long long` and a `double` are both 8 bytes long on your system:

```
typedef union { long long a; double b } my_union;

int main()
{
    my_union c;
    c.b = 1.0;
    c.a--;
    std::cout << "Double value is " << c.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Long long value is " << c.a << std::endl;
}
```

Here you don't need to know ahead of time what the bit representation of 1.0 is.

Comment: That leads to UB, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 0):

This `0x1.fffffffffffffp-1` syntax is great, but only in C99 or C++17.

But there is a workaround, no (pointer-)casting, no UB/IB, just simple math.

```
double x = (double)0x1fffffffffffff / (1LL << 53);
```

If I need a Pi, and Pi(double) is 0x1.921fb54442d18p1 in hex, just write

```
const double PI = (double)0x1921fb54442d18 / (1LL << 51);
```

If your constant has large or small exponent, you could use the function `exp2` instead of the shift, but `exp2` is C99/C++11 ... Use `pow` for rescue!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than all the bit juggling, the most direct solution is to use `nextafter()` from `math.h`. Thus:

```
#include <math.h>
double a = nextafter(1.0, 0.0);
```

Read this as: the next floating-point value after `1.0` in the direction of `0.0`; an almost direct encoding of "the closest number below 1.0" from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

https://godbolt.org/z/MTY4v4exz

```
typedef union { long long a; double b; } my_union;

int main()
{
    my_union c;
    c.b = 1.0;
    c.a--;
    std::cout << "Double value is " << c.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Long long value is " << c.a << std::endl;
}
```